# Auto Sorting List Alphabetically

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to simply sort unordered lists when they have the following ID.

The code works in a fiddle perfectly https://jsfiddle.net/w19Lbjqt/2/

but when i try to run it on my site it doesn't work or give me any errors. any ideas?

```
function sortUL(selector) {
var unsortedList = jQuery(selector);
unsortedList.find('li').sort(function (a, b) {
    var upA = jQuery(a).text().toUpperCase();
    var upB = jQuery(b).text().toUpperCase();
    return (upA < upB) ? -1 : (upA > upB) ? 1 : 0;
}).appendTo(selector);
};

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    sortUL("#sortList");
});
```

Comment: How are you trying to run it on your site? Where are you enqueueing it?

Comment: Open the browser dev tools (press F12 on Chrome or FF), go to "Console" and paste your code. If things work as you want, then your code is not being loaded and you should investigate why. You can also use the dev tools for this (check if your JS file is being loaded on the "network" tab).

Comment: I verified my scripts file is for sure being loaded. Its being enqueued from my functions file. Any other ideas?

Comment: when trying to add the code to the console directly it does nothing also. no errors. nothing.  Page in question (https://employee.provo.edu/human-resource/job-descriptions/administration-services/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by adjust my call slightly.  instead of using

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    sortUL("#sortList");
});
```

I used

```
jQuery(window).on("load", function() {
     sortUL("#sortList");
});
```

seems that either SHOULD have worked, but this worked for me nonetheless

Comment: may be its because your sortURL function was outside document ready